# Renaming fragments on SPSS

Tags: spss

I am not used to SPSS so this question will sound stupid:

I need to change fragments of a cell in spss, exemple:

'1.28' 
'2.69'
'3.57'
 to 
'a.28'
'b.69'
'c.57'

What's the best way to do it?

Tks.

Answer (score 2):

This is assuming the variable you want to recode is called 'VarA', and that it is numeric.

This creates a copy of the variable, converts it to a string, and then uses those values to create a new version that is recoded.

```
RECODE VarA (ELSE = COPY) INTO VarA_String.
ALTER TYPE  VarA_String(A8).
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE VarA_r=REPLACE(VarA_String,'1.','a.').
COMPUTE VarA_r=REPLACE(VarA_String,'2.','b.').
COMPUTE VarA_r=REPLACE(VarA_String,'3.','c.').
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is a little different in SPSS Modeler and bear with me as I can only attach one image until I have a certain reputation on SO.

After you convert VarA into a string (which I called to_str) you can use the replace command to change part of the substring, ie:

```
    to_string(VarA)
```

for the first Derive node, and:

```
    replace('1.','a.',to_str)
```

for the second Derive node, this command replaces all occurrences of SUBSTRING1 with SUBSTRING2 in STRING and you will get the same result but in Modeler, see the sample stream [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQA0b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these are strings, see the replace function in COMPUTE.  If there are just a few, though, just edit the cells in the Data Editor.